# Why does private field have a value of “undefined” inside private method of it's own component in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing an authorization component for my **angular2** app:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IAuthData } from './auth-data';
import { IAuthResult } from './auth-result';
import { AuthorizationService } from './authorization.service';
import { NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'authorization.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'authorization.component.css' ],
    moduleId: module.id
})
export class AuthorizationComponent implements OnInit {
    private _authorizationService: AuthorizationService;
    private _notificationsService: NotificationsService;

    constructor(private authorizationService: AuthorizationService, private notificationsService: NotificationsService) {
        this._authorizationService = authorizationService;
        this._notificationsService = notificationsService;
    }

    public pageTitle: string = 'AUTHORIZATION';
    public login: string;
    public password: string;

    ngOnInit() : void {

    }

    authorize(): void {
        this._notificationsService.info(this.pageTitle, `Authorization attempt for "${this.login}": sending auth query to the server.`);
        this._authorizationService.authorize(<IAuthData>{ login: this.login, hash: this.password })
            .subscribe(authResult => {
                let message: string = `"${this.login}": ${authResult.message}`;
                if (authResult.isAuthorized) {
                    this._notificationsService.info(this.pageTitle, message);
                }
                else {
                    this._notificationsService.error(this.pageTitle, message);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but, in refactoring purposes, I've decided to move lambda expression code from `subscribe` into separate method:

```
private processAuthResult(authResult: IAuthData): void {
     let message: string = `"${this.login}": ${authResult.message}`;
                    if (authResult.isAuthorized) {
                        this._notificationsService.info(this.pageTitle, message);
                    }
                    else {
                        this._notificationsService.error(this.pageTitle, message);
                    }let message: string = `"${this.login}": ${authResult.message}`;
                    if (authResult.isAuthorized) {
                        this._notificationsService.info(this.pageTitle, message);
                    }
                    else {
                        this._notificationsService.error(this.pageTitle, message);
                    }
}
```

Since I did it, field `this._notificationsService` has a value of `undefined` inside `pocessAuthResult()` method. I use this method like this:

```
authorize(): void {
            this._notificationsService.info(this.pageTitle, `Authorization attempt for "${this.login}": sending auth query to the server.`);
            this._authorizationService.authorize(<IAuthData>{ login: this.login, hash: this.password })
                .subscribe(this.processAuthResult);
        }
```

What's the reason?

Comment: because I guess you put `obs.subscribe(this.processAuthResult)`

Comment: How do you use this method?

Comment: @echonax this is the same thing.... @klutch1991 use `obs.subscribe(this.processAuthResult.bind(this))` or `obs.subscribe((data)=>this.processAuthResult(data))`.

Comment: @echonax, updated question

Comment: @echonax convinced ? My crystal ball never lies...

Comment: @n00dl3 yep :-) good guess on the usage, I assumed es6 syntax was used. From now on, I'll trust your crystal ball :P

Comment: @n00dl3 Who will write the answer?)

Comment: @yurzui I think we're waiting for it to be closed (duplicate) :-)